# stored function - syntax to format data of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

Much appreciated if you can have a quick look on the below.

I've created the below stored function in order to format the datetime from a table to mysql format;
(%Y-%m-%d; %h:%i:%s);

```
    Delimiter $$

      create function formatdata(dataparameter varchar(20), hourparametru 
    varchar(20)) 
    begin
    DECLARE x time;
    declare y date;
    set x = (select STR_TO_DATE(Datăcolumn,'%h:%i:%s')from tabelname);
    set y = (select STR_TO_DATE(oracolumn,'%Y-%m-%d')from tabelname);
    select x,y;
    if current_time > time(hourcolumn) then
    select STR_TO_DATE(Datăcolumn,'%Y-%m-%d')into x from tabelname;
    select STR_TO_DATE(oracolumn,'%h:%i:%s') into y from tabelname;
    return(x,y);
    end if;
    end $$
    Delimiter ;
```

What am I doing wrong here?
The error is You have an error in your sql syntax near first select_Str_to_date.
but I am kind of confused how local variables, IN parameters work together - so I am assuming that here is where I do wrong..

Comment: the parameters for str_to_date should represent the format you are converting  not what you want to convert to. Also user defined variables ('@' variable are not the same as declared variables. And you can only return 1 value.

Comment: After your edit it is unclear where `Datăcolumn` and `oracolumn` are getting their values from.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Now I have a new error Not allowed to return  a result set from a function. But why? I do have the local variables...

Comment: The thing is I need to have two columns modified by the function (1st column is date and the 2nd is hour); should I use table-valued functions - modify the RETURNS?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a variable to a result of a scalar SELECT query, you put the query inside parentheses.

This:

```
set x = select STR_TO_DATE('07:47:20','%h:%i:%s');
```

Should be:

```
set x = (select STR_TO_DATE('07:47:20','%h:%i:%s'));
```

That explains the syntax error.

You also have a few other problems in this function.

---

Re your comment:

The line:

```
select x,y;
```

Would return a result set, but that's not allowed in a stored function (it is allowed in a stored procedure). I think you can just remove this line.

A stored function can only return a single scalar value. You should have a line `RETURNS <datatype>` before your `BEGIN`, and you should `RETURN` a single value somewhere in your function.

Another problem: your assignments are not valid if the table has more than one row. Setting a variable to a scalar SELECT query result is valid only if the query returns a single column and single row.

Another problem:

```
if current_time > time(hourcolumn) then
```

What is `hourcolumn`? It's not a function parameter or a local variable. But if it is a column of a table, there's no syntax to say which table you mean.

Another problem:

```
return(x,y);
```

You can't return a pair of variables from a stored function. Only one variable.

Another problem: The only `RETURN` is inside an `IF` block. What should the function return if the `IF` condition isn't true?

Comment: Thanks, Bill. Can you please point them out in order to be able to correcT? I've just edited the above syntax. and now I get an error message  Not allowed to return a result set from a function. But why?